# Dynamic DataTable to Entities *without* hard coding in advance...?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Question:

Q: Why can't/How can I dynamically use the data in the DataTable to craft the LINQ/EF in a function that uses reflection(?) to create instances of the entities based on what is available?

I have seen many, many Qs & As about *hard coding*, but none on doing this *dynamically*. I'm looking for an alternative to having to maintain hard-coded code for all my entities...

**Background/verification of my approach:**

1. I am in a situation where I have lots and lots of Entities.
2. I'm using EF6 Code-First, MVC5 and ASP.NET, and an admin would upload a spreadsheet. Each workbook is converted to a DataSet, and each tab (worksheet) to a DataTable.
3. *All this I am doing well*, with the DataTable name as the name of the entity class.
4. The user is given a template spreadsheet that already has the names of the columns they need to fill in as the top row. I'll fix having to o that manually after this problem. [Users should be able to select a class, and a workbook should be made for them to download dynamically with the appropriate column headers, but that is on the list]
5. My question here starts with a filled in worksheet that has been brought into a DataTable for each class, determined by it's tab name/datatable name.

**Given:**
-I know the name of the class (from dt.Name), and I verified already that is a valid entity.
-I know the names of columns I'll be updating with each DataRow, as they are in the dt's column names.

Question restated, now with context:
Why can't/How can I dynamically use the data in the DataTable to craft the LINQ/EF in a function that uses reflection(?) to create instances of the entities based on what is available?

```
[Pseudo-Code]
public void DataTableToEntities(DataTable dt){
    string entityClassName = dt.Name;
    ArrayList/List<string> colNames = dt.Columns. names, ...
    ....
    using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext()){
        while (row dtRow in dtRows){
            // magic follows:
            DeterminedEntity de = new DeterminedEntity();
            // populate de with dtRow
            ctx.[DeterminedEntity].Add(de);
            // magic ends...
        }
        ctx.SaveChanges;
    }
}
```

**Rationale:**

I can add, edit, and remove entities at will, without having to hard code those subtle changes in an import scenario as above.

Next step: tackling dynamic workbook & worksheet creation as upload template for above process, with *WorkBook -> DataSet*, and *WorkSheets -> DataTables*.

**Progress:**
11/6/2016

The crux of this problem seems to be how to instantiate an instance of the DBContext class's entity from just a name.

My Scratch console app is a separate project (same solution), with all the models & stuff copied over...

So far I've got:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ScratchProgram s = new ScratchConsole1.ScratchProgram();
    Console.WriteLine("starting");
    string fileLocation = @"C:\Users\...\SomeDbSetClass_test.xlsx";
    string tableName = "SomeDbSetClass";
    //----------------------------------------------------------
    // FreeSpire.xls
    Workbook wb = new Workbook();
    wb.LoadFromFile(fileLocation);
    Console.WriteLine("wb.WorkSheets count: " + wb.Worksheets.Count);
    //----------------------------------------------------------
    Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[tableName];
    Console.WriteLine("ws.Rows count: " + ws.Rows.Count());
    //----------------------------------------------------------
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(tableName);
    dt = ws.ExportDataTable();
    Console.WriteLine("dt.Rows.Count: " + dt.Rows.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("dt.Name: " + dt.TableName);
    //==========================================================
    string pathToAssembly = @"C:\...\ScratchConsole1.dll";
    var aClass = s.CreateInstanceOf(dt.TableName, pathToAssembly);
    // Now I have a valid class of the program-NOT the ef ctx...
    Console.WriteLine("aClass.FullName: " + aClass.GetType().FullName);

    MethodInfo[] aMethods = aClass.GetType().GetMethods();
    // now I have an array of all get/sets... "get_<method>" and "set_<method>"
    // let's iterate through all the methods, printing them:
    for (int i2 = 0;i2 < aMethods.Count() ; i2++)
    {
        MethodInfo mi = aMethods[i2];
        Console.WriteLine("method: " + mi.Name);
    }
    // the above isn't really useful, as I already have the property names in the dt header row
    using (DatabaseContext ctx = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        //==========================================================
        // i is used as column index below, as dr.ItemArray is an array...
        int i = 0; 
        // each dr should create a new instance of the ctx's ef class...
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            ???
            ...Create new instance in ctx, using as class name: dt.TableName...
            ctxClass <--- assuming made using aClass
            ???

            // now we can load each class property with the value from the dr:
            foreach (string drItem in dr.ItemArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("================= col ================="));
                string entAttrName = dt.Columns[i].ToString(); // this is fine as string, but...
                string entAttrValue = dr[i].ToString(); // this is NOT <--- see Note1 below

                Console.WriteLine("[" + i + "] Item: " + entAttrName.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("[" + i + "] Value: " + entAttrValue.ToString());

                ???
                ctxClass.[entAttrName.ToString()] = entAttrValue.ToString(); <--- see Note1 below
                ???

                //==============================================================================
                // Note1:
                // the above is far less than ideal, as it has every column/attribute/property type // being used as a String... Obviously, we want to leave doubles as doubles, ints as // ints, etc.
                
                // This becomes a MUCH larger problem when we introduce entities as properties... 
                // like a State entity with many City entities as a List<State> as a property...
                //==============================================================================
                i++;
            }
            ctx.[ef class].Add(ctxClass);
        }
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("end.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public object CreateInstanceOf(string ClassName, string AssemblyFullPath)
{
    var assemblyFullPath = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\...\ScratchConsole1.exe");
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var type = assembly.GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == ClassName);
    return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

I hope this makes things easier to understand.:)

UPDATE AND SOLUTION! An SO user, [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold), solved the problem with a single line changed on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496667/how-can-i-dynamically-add-inherited-properties-to-ef-datastore?noredirect=1#comment68237920_40496667):

```
// All details from the property to update/set:
//PropertyInfo theProp = thisTypeInfo.GetDeclaredProperty(entAttrName);
PropertyInfo theProp = thisTypeInfo.GetProperty(entAttrName);
```

Gert's explanation:

> thisTypeInfo.GetDeclaredProperty gets properties declared by the type
> itself, not its supertype. Use thisTypeInfo.GetProperty. – Gert Arnold

I can't believe I was able to frame a problem I barely understood in a way that smarter people could resolve!

===========================================================================

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here in a sentence:

*This program takes a spreadsheet file (.xlsx), reads the tab names for EF DbSet classes, and the column names & values for property names and values, and saves them as individual entities in the data store of your EF install (works with both SQLite & SQL Server 2014)*.

The cool part is that there need be no hard coding in the application for EF class names, properties, etc. This means you can create an Excel *template*, have someone fill it in (just the columns you give them in the template), and that file can be imported without further hassle.

Everything you need to recreate for yourself is in this post.

I wanted this for my own application I'm writing, and was a little surprised that nobody had wanted to do the same thing. With 100s of EF classes, and base classes, the answers (even here) were to hunker down, bite the bullet, and hard code everything.

I'm going to post *working code* here as complete as I can. This code is hopefully a HUGE step forward for anyone trying to make their software easier to use. In order to *completely* isolate the question/Poc/Answer, I used:

VS 2015, SQLite latest, SQLite.CodeFirst, System.Data.SQLite[.Linq and .EF6] (<- may not all be necessary, but I struggled 1st time with SQLite), NLog, NLog.Config, Spire.XLS, EF6... that should be it. Everything was done in NuGet.

Notes:
-I use SQL 2014 Ent in my normal system, but found that SQLite has the same performance. In fact, this example and timings below are on an SQLite database file!
-The timings below are on my dev laptop, which is running Win10 in a VirtBox VM with VS2015 on it. Another VM on the same laptop is running SQL 2014 Enterprise, but for this test example I used SQLite on the same Win10 VM.
-My *MyDbContext.cs* and *Configuration.cs* files are bare bones, no seeding, etc.

```
public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }
```

-There is a simple test.xlsx file that has the values to insert into DB.

Here is the .csv of it:

```
sChildFoo,iChildBar,dChildBaz,PersonAge,PersonWeight,PersonName
Norwich,29884,1.2,34,123,Fred Flintstone
Waterford,34990,3.4,56,210,Barney Rubble
```

Important: The tab in the worksheet is labeled **Child**-exactly the same as the class you want the values loaded as. There are 2 data/entity classes, Person() and Child() called *PersonChild.cs*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DynamicEFLoading
{
    public abstract class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public int PersonAge { get; set; }
        public int PersonWeight { get; set; }
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
    }
    class Child : Person
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string sChildFoo { get; set; }
        public int iChildBar { get; set; }
        public double dChildBaz { get; set; }
    }
}
```

All Child() instances inherit properties from Person(), as you can see. I even made Person() abstract.

Here is the substance, as decorated as I dared in comments, *TestProgram.cs*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using NLog;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Spire.Xls;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;

namespace DynamicEFLoading
{
    class TestProgram
    {
        private static Logger logit = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        static void Main()
        {
            DateTime dtStart = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            DateTime dtStop = new DateTime();
            TestProgram s = new TestProgram();
            Utils u = new Utils();
            s.p("Starting at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            // for this test, I leave this door open the whole time...
            using (MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext())
            {
                //###########################################################################
                //
                // create a row in db each time run...
                //
                Random rnd = new Random();
                // 
                Child c1 = new DynamicEFLoading.Child();
                // Age, Weight, Name all come from base class Person()
                c1.PersonAge = rnd.Next(120);
                c1.PersonWeight = rnd.Next(85, 300);
                c1.PersonName = String.Format("{0} {1}", Utils.GenerateName(6), Utils.GenerateName(8));
                s.p(String.Format("Created .Name: {0}", c1.PersonName));
                //
                c1.dChildBaz = rnd.NextDouble();
                c1.iChildBar = rnd.Next(99999);
                c1.sChildFoo = String.Format("{0}", Utils.GenerateName(10));
                s.p(String.Format("Created .sParentFoo: {0}", c1.sChildFoo));
                //
                ctx.Children.Add(c1);
                //_______________________________________________________
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                //###########################################################################
                //
                // in production, there would be no hard coding...
                //
                string fileLocation = @"C:\Users\<some user>\Desktop\test.xlsx";
                //
                // NOTE! Here I am specifying the only tab(ws name) in the wb. This is easily changed 
                //      to access all tabs by index, using Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[index], and
                //      a simple loop through them all. In my first test, I even verify the tab had
                //      a corresponding table in DB before continuing... 
                string tableName = "Child";
                //----------------------------------------------------------
                // freeSpire.xls
                Workbook wb = new Workbook();
                wb.LoadFromFile(fileLocation);
                //----------------------------------------------------------
                // see NOTE! just above...
                Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[tableName];
                //----------------------------------------------------------
                // create a DataTable
                DataTable dt = new DataTable(tableName);
                // load it with data from whoile worksheet (ws)
                dt = ws.ExportDataTable();
                // from now on, we use DataTable-not spreadsheet
                //----------------------------------------------------------
                s.p(String.Format("wb.WorkSheets count: " + wb.Worksheets.Count));
                s.p(String.Format("ws.Rows count: " + ws.Rows.Count()));
                s.p(String.Format("dt.Rows.Count: " + dt.Rows.Count));
                s.p(String.Format("dt.Name: " + dt.TableName));
                //==========================================================
                // getting assembly name programmatically fails when a project is inside a solution
                //  in VS. It assumes ...\ProjName\ProjName\... whis isn't how solutions go... 
                string pathToAssembly = @"C:\Users\<some user>\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DynamicEFLoading\DynamicEFLoading\bin\Debug\DynamicEfLoading.exe";
                // string pathToAssembly = @".\DynamicEfLoading.exe";
                // create an 'anonymous', or ghost class:
                var aClass = u.CreateInstanceOf(dt.TableName, pathToAssembly);
                // display class type
                s.p(String.Format("aClass.FullName: " + aClass.GetType().FullName));
                //==========================================================
                //
                // creating a DbSet for the dt's entities. It isn't good enough to just create
                //  the class itself-it needs to be from the DbContext (ctx). or else you can't
                //  ctx.SaveChanges();    
                //
                s.p(String.Format("Creating 'dbs' object..."));
                DbSet dbs = ctx.Set(aClass.GetType());
                // But you can't att attributes/properties to a DbSet-only to the class it is
                //  derived from, so we then use the DbSet (dbs) for this class to create an
                //  empty class that we can populate & later add to DB via ctx:
                var theObj = dbs.Create(aClass.GetType());
                // make sure it's the right one:
                s.p(String.Format("GetType: " + theObj.GetType()));
                //____________________________________________________________________________
                int i = 0; // used to keep track of each column as we go through the dt
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) // each dr in the dt is a separate instance of the theObj class
                {
                    s.p(String.Format("================= row =================================="));
                    i = 0; // I don't like to put var instantiation in a loop...
                    // each drItem is the content for the row (theObj)
                    foreach (string drItem in dr.ItemArray)
                    {
                        s.p(String.Format("================= col {0} ", i));
                        string entAttrName = dt.Columns[i].ToString();
                        string entAttrValue = dr[i].ToString();
                        // column (property) name:
                        s.p("[" + i + "] Item: " + entAttrName.ToString());
                        // the value of that property to load into this class' property
                        s.p("[" + i + "] Value: " + entAttrValue.ToString());
                        // which type of data is this property? (string, int32, double...)
                        // -also has data like if nullable, etc. of use in later refinements...
                        TypeInfo thisTypeInfo = theObj.GetType().GetTypeInfo();
                        // All details from the property to update/set:
                        PropertyInfo theProp = thisTypeInfo.GetProperty(entAttrName);
                        //___________________________________________________________________
                        // need to determine the property type, converting entAttrValuefrom string:
                        // good debugging info at this stage to see what we've discovered from the class dynamically at rn time...
                        s.p("theProp.DeclaringType.FullName of attr: " + theProp.DeclaringType.FullName);
                        s.p("theProp.GetSetMethod(true).ToString() of attr: " + theProp.GetSetMethod(true).ToString());
                        s.p("theProp.GetType().ToString() of attr: " + theProp.GetType().ToString());
                        s.p("theProp.Name of attr: " + theProp.Name);
                        s.p("theProp.PropertyType.ToString() of attr: " + theProp.PropertyType.ToString());
                        s.p("theProp.ReflectedType.ToString() of attr: " + theProp.ReflectedType.ToString());
                        s.p("theProp.ReflectedType.ToString() of attr: " + theProp.SetMethod.ReturnType.ToString());
                       /* update entAttrName with entAttrValue:
                        *
                        * At this point, my values in the DataTable are all strings, but the class itself 
                        *   stores that value as who-knows-what. So here I just parse out what kind it is from three
                        *   common types. In future, may need to add more, but for now, these are the big 4: 
                        * 
                        * String, Integer, DatTime, and Double
                        */
                        if (theProp.PropertyType.ToString() == "System.String")
                        {
                            theProp.SetValue(theObj, (String)entAttrValue);
                            logit.Debug("Set {0} value: {1}",
                                theProp.PropertyType.ToString(),
                                entAttrValue);
                        }
                        else if (theProp.PropertyType.ToString().Contains("System.Int32"))
                        {
                            theProp.SetValue(theObj, int.Parse(entAttrValue));
                            logit.Debug("Set {0} value: {1}",
                                theProp.PropertyType.ToString(),
                                entAttrValue);
                        }
                        else if (theProp.PropertyType.ToString().Contains("System.DateTime"))
                        {
                            IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
                            DateTime dTime = DateTime.Parse(entAttrValue, culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
                            theProp.SetValue(theObj, entAttrValue);
                            logit.Debug("Set {0} value: {1}",
                                theProp.PropertyType.ToString(),
                                entAttrValue);
                        }
                        else if (theProp.PropertyType.ToString().Contains("System.Double"))
                        {
                            theProp.SetValue(theObj, double.Parse(entAttrValue));
                            logit.Debug("Set {0} value: {1}",
                                theProp.PropertyType.ToString(),
                                entAttrValue);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            logit.Error("Unexpected property type: {0} given. string value: {1}",
                                theProp.PropertyType.ToString(),
                                entAttrValue
                            );
                        }
                        i++; // increment column index...
                    } // end foreach (string drItem in dr.ItemArray...
                    // add class to context...
                    dbs.Add(theObj);
                    // to save one by one (each row):
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                } // end of foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows...
                  // or... to save as batch (at end of worksheet):
                  // ctx.SaveChanges();
                  //###########################################################################
                dtStop = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
                TimeSpan tsDuration = dtStop - dtStart;
                s.p(String.Format("end... took {0} seconds.", tsDuration.TotalSeconds.ToString()));
                Console.ReadKey();
            } // end using DbContext...
        }
        /*
         * Convenience; writes to both...
         * 
         */
        //private static void p(string message)
        private void p(string message)
        {
            logit.Info(message);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, this is the *Utils.cs* file that holds the Utils() class. You see these referred to above as "u.*", instantiated way at the top of TestProgram.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NLog;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;

namespace DynamicEFLoading
{
    class Utils
    {
        private static Logger logit = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public ArrayList HeadersFromDataTable(DataTable theDataTable)
        {
            ArrayList arHeaders = new ArrayList();
            try
            {
                arHeaders.AddRange(theDataTable.Columns);
                logit.Info("loaded {0} column headers...", arHeaders.Count);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logit.Fatal("exception: " + ex.ToString());
            }
            return arHeaders;
        }

        public object CreateInstanceOf(string ClassName, string AssemblyFullPath)
        {
            var assemblyFullPath = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Users\<some user>\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PoliticWebSite\ScratchConsole1\bin\Debug\ScratchConsole1.exe");
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            //var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFullPath);
            var type = assembly.GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == ClassName);
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }

        public static string GenerateName(int len)
        {
            Random rndSeed = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            Random r = new Random(rndSeed.Next());
            string[] consonants = { "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "l", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "sh", "zh", "t", "v", "w", "x" };
            string[] vowels = { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "ae", "y" };
            string Name = "";
            Name += consonants[r.Next(consonants.Length)].ToUpper();
            Name += vowels[r.Next(vowels.Length)];
            int b = 2; //b tells how many times a new letter has been added. It's 2 right now because the first two letters are already in the name.
            while (b < len)
            {
                //_________________________________________________________________
                rndSeed = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
                r = new Random(rndSeed.Next());
                Name += consonants[r.Next(consonants.Length)];
                b++;
                //_________________________________________________________________
                rndSeed = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
                r = new Random(rndSeed.Next());
                Name += vowels[r.Next(vowels.Length)];
                b++;
                //_________________________________________________________________
            }
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

So what does all this look like, as the program goes through each column (which can be in any order, BTW)?

```
2016-11-08 22:18:14.2500 INFO Starting at 10:18:14 PM
2016-11-08 22:18:14.3499 INFO Created .Name: Tytaetae Tytaetaetae
2016-11-08 22:18:14.3499 INFO Created .sParentFoo: Baebabababa
2016-11-08 22:18:15.2181 INFO wb.WorkSheets count: 2
2016-11-08 22:18:15.2181 INFO ws.Rows count: 3
2016-11-08 22:18:15.2338 INFO dt.Rows.Count: 2
2016-11-08 22:18:15.2338 INFO dt.Name: Child
2016-11-08 22:18:15.2487 INFO aClass.FullName: DynamicEFLoading.Child
2016-11-08 22:18:15.2487 INFO Creating 'dbs' object...
2016-11-08 22:18:15.2644 INFO GetType: DynamicEFLoading.Child
2016-11-08 22:18:15.2644 INFO ================= row ==================================
2016-11-08 22:18:15.2644 INFO ================= col 0 
2016-11-08 22:18:15.2801 INFO [0] Item: sChildFoo
2016-11-08 22:18:15.2801 INFO [0] Value: Norwich
2016-11-08 22:18:15.2801 INFO theProp.DeclaringType.FullName of attr: DynamicEFLoading.Child
2016-11-08 22:18:15.2958 INFO theProp.GetSetMethod(true).ToString() of attr: Void set_sChildFoo(System.String)
2016-11-08 22:18:15.2958 INFO theProp.GetType().ToString() of attr: System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo
2016-11-08 22:18:15.3114 INFO theProp.Name of attr: sChildFoo
2016-11-08 22:18:15.3114 INFO theProp.PropertyType.ToString() of attr: System.String
2016-11-08 22:18:15.3271 INFO theProp.ReflectedType.ToString() of attr: DynamicEFLoading.Child
2016-11-08 22:18:15.3271 INFO theProp.ReflectedType.ToString() of attr: System.Void
2016-11-08 22:18:15.3271 DEBUG Set System.String value: Norwich
2016-11-08 22:18:15.3428 INFO ================= col 1 
...
2016-11-08 22:18:16.1237 INFO ================= row ==================================
2016-11-08 22:18:16.1394 INFO ================= col 0 
2016-11-08 22:18:16.1394 INFO [0] Item: sChildFoo
2016-11-08 22:18:16.1551 INFO [0] Value: Waterford
2016-11-08 22:18:16.1551 INFO theProp.DeclaringType.FullName of attr: DynamicEFLoading.Child
2016-11-08 22:18:16.1551 INFO theProp.GetSetMethod(true).ToString() of attr: Void set_sChildFoo(System.String)
2016-11-08 22:18:16.1707 INFO theProp.GetType().ToString() of attr: System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo
2016-11-08 22:18:16.1863 INFO theProp.Name of attr: sChildFoo
2016-11-08 22:18:16.1863 INFO theProp.PropertyType.ToString() of attr: System.String
2016-11-08 22:18:16.1863 INFO theProp.ReflectedType.ToString() of attr: DynamicEFLoading.Child
2016-11-08 22:18:16.2020 INFO theProp.ReflectedType.ToString() of attr: System.Void
2016-11-08 22:18:16.2020 DEBUG Set System.String value: Waterford
2016-11-08 22:18:16.2179 INFO ================= col 1 
...
2016-11-08 22:18:16.5772 INFO ================= col 5 
2016-11-08 22:18:16.5772 INFO [5] Item: PersonName
2016-11-08 22:18:16.5772 INFO [5] Value: Barney Rubble
2016-11-08 22:18:16.5772 INFO theProp.DeclaringType.FullName of attr: DynamicEFLoading.Person
2016-11-08 22:18:16.5927 INFO theProp.GetSetMethod(true).ToString() of attr: Void set_PersonName(System.String)
2016-11-08 22:18:16.5927 INFO theProp.GetType().ToString() of attr: System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo
2016-11-08 22:18:16.5927 INFO theProp.Name of attr: PersonName
2016-11-08 22:18:16.6084 INFO theProp.PropertyType.ToString() of attr: System.String
2016-11-08 22:18:16.6084 INFO theProp.ReflectedType.ToString() of attr: DynamicEFLoading.Child
2016-11-08 22:18:16.6240 INFO theProp.ReflectedType.ToString() of attr: System.Void
2016-11-08 22:18:16.6240 DEBUG Set System.String value: Barney Rubble
2016-11-08 22:18:16.6397 INFO end... took 2.391686 seconds.
```

2.4 seconds to load the file, parse it to a DataSet/DataTable, then convert them to classes and EF instances, checking each column for validity. All in a Win10 VM on a Linux laptop.
 

For now, I offer you (my messy & inefficient) solution to grabbing & saving EF data without hard coding anything but the header row of your Excel template.

**To-Dos:**
-add looping through the workbook, doing all worksheets.
-add verifying class indicated in datatable actually exists in EF (I do this in my pilot code).
-add verifying file is a valid .xlsx file (Spire has this feature) before importing, etc.

I spent many hours on this to make it work, and since I am in way over my head from my normal programming, I would appreciate any feedback on making it better/safer/etc. I did this by stumbling through Intellisense and books, mostly.

==================================================================

Comment: If you look closely, you see that the column types (EF Property) _types_ are checked for each and every row-even though after the first row we know the Type (int, string, ...). I can make this faster by noting & remembering these on the first row, and referring to those types in subsequent rows. I will keep the upgraded versions on a blog.